# How to check if x int start from y int via bits operations?

Tags: swift, math, bit

I need to check if x int start from other (y) int for example:

```
1) input: x = 1250; y = 12 output: True

2) input: x = 2500; y = 250 output: True

3) input: x = 22; y = 21 output: False

4) input: x = 150; y = 11 output: False
```

And I have no idea how to do it.

I have tried to use & operator but it is not enough:

```
let result = y & x
if result == y {
    print("good")
}
```

How I can check it by using bit operations not using strings?

Comment: Is this `C++`, `C`, or `Swift`? You've tagged all three!

Comment: @EricPostpischil, not exactly, since `x != y * t`, in fact `x == y * t + C` where `0 <= C < t`. So, another hint: @Arkhyp Koshel, division is more likely to help you than multiplication, I suppose.

Comment: If two numbers start with the same digits in base-10, it doesn't mean their first digits in base-2 will be the same: 230 and 23 start with the same digits, but their binary equivalents, 0b11100110 and 0b10111, do not.

Comment: @Martin it is not matter for me, C++|C|Swift ok or even other languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it via bits operations, like @ForceBru mentions in comment.

You can do it without using strings: just calculate digits count in both numbers, then "cut" bigger number and then compare if these numbers are equal:

```
func checkPrefix(_ prefix: Int, for number: Int) -> Bool {
    let digitsDiff = digits(for: number) - digits(for: prefix)

    if digitsDiff <= 0 {
        return false
    }

    let digitsDiffPower = pow(10, Double(digitsDiff))

    return number / Int(digitsDiffPower) == prefix
}

func digits(for number: Int) -> Int {
    var num = number
    var count = 0
    while num != 0 {
        count += 1
        num = num / 10
    }
    return count
}
```

It works like you described:

```
print(checkPrefix(12, for: 1250)) // prints: true
print(checkPrefix(250, for: 2500)) // prints: true
print(checkPrefix(21, for: 22)) // prints: false
print(checkPrefix(11, for: 150)) // prints: false
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of your comment that it doesn't matter which language this is in, here's a lazy C# implementation (that will port to C if you `#include <stdbool.h>`) that relies on the fact that integer division returns an `int`:

```
bool CheckPrefix(int x, int y)
{
    while (y > x)
        if ((y /= 10) == x)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

In C#:

```
Console.WriteLine(CheckPrefix(12, 1250));
Console.WriteLine(CheckPrefix(250, 2500));
Console.WriteLine(CheckPrefix(21, 22));
Console.WriteLine(CheckPrefix(11, 150));
```

Outputs:

```
True
True
False
False
```

In C:

```
printf("%s", CheckPrefix(12, 1250) ? "true" : "false");
printf("%s", CheckPrefix(250, 2500) ? "true" : "false");
printf("%s", CheckPrefix(21, 22) ? "true" : "false");
printf("%s", CheckPrefix(11, 150) ? "true" : "false");
```

Outputs:

```
truetruefalsefalse
```